# Clam shell mode without external display, keyboard, mouse

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a latest 13 inch MBP retina, running 10.10.

I am wondering, is there a way to run the machine with the lids closed **WITHOUT** an external monitor, keyboard, and mouse?

We are using the machine as a server in a confined space, and would like to keep the machine closed, but still running.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not natively, but you can use an app like InsomniaX to prevent the device from sleeping when the lid is closed.

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22211/insomniax